# EF поле сущности не устанавливается в null

Tags: c#

```
var service = db.Services.Find(orderDto.IdService);
var customer = db.Customers.Find(orderDto.CustomerId);
var jobDay = db.JobDays.Find(id);

order.Sum = orderDto.Sum;
order.IsSale = orderDto.IsSale;
order.IsCash = orderDto.IsСash;

order.Service = service;
order.JobDay = jobDay;
order.Customer = customer;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Поле `Customer` допускает значение `null`. При попытке его устновить в `null`, оно остается прежним. Как это победить?

Comment: Вы можете показать код, где присваиваете полю новое значение? Есть подозрение, что вы не записываете изменения в контекст. В любом случае, без подробностей понять в чём проблема невозможно

Comment: order.Customer = customer; приходит id равный null, db.Customers.Find(orderDto.CustomerId); возвращает null и этот null присваивается. Я для проверки писал просто : order.Customer=null. Устанавливается, но только со второго раза.

Comment: Ну, очевидно, проблема в `orderDto.CustomerId` - в БД нет записи с таким ID, соответственно, результаты поиска пустые. Попробуйте для начала получить запись с заведомо существующим индексом, и, если всё получится, разбирайтесь, что у вас не так с `orderDto`